# Hamachi doesn't connect to network without windows login

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, hamachi

When using Hamachi, it doesn't connect to network without windows login. After a login (via rdp, I dont think that matters), it connects perfectly, and when the rdp connection stops, it almost immediately disconnects from the hamachi network.

Note that the rdp connection stops but the user isn't logged off - the session is retained. Also, the Hamachi2Svc service runs all the time. Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it's all part of the new LogMeIn hamachi changes - We were quite busy yesterday!

[Hamachi changes](http://b.logme.in/2012/11/07/changes-to-hamachi-on-november-19th/)

> we’re making a small change to Hamachi: unless a computer is part of a paid network, you need to be logged in and running the Hamachi UI on your desktop in order to allow it to function

Which is unfortunate because I've been using hamachi from the very start :(

To get round this - perform an auto log on then initiate a lock command in the startup folder or something